# Hive variable concatenation

Tags: variables, hive, concatenation

I am facing problems in concatenating the value of a variable with a string .
my script contains the below

```
set hivevar:tab_dt= substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10);

CREATE TABLE default.udr_lt_bc_${hivevar:tab_dt}
(
trans_id double 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

in the above, the variable tab_dt gets assigned correctly with yesterdays date in the format yyyymmdd.
but when i try to concatenate this variable in a table name with a static string, the script fails. it is not doing the concatenation .
Kindly provide a solution.

note: i tried the below too, which is erroring out too

```
set hivevar:tab_dt= substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10);
set hivevar:tab_nm1= default.udr_lt_bc_;
set hivevar:tab_name= concat(${hivevar:tab_dt},${hivevar:tab_nm1})

CREATE TABLE ${hivevar:tab_name}
(
trans_id double 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

This too is returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not calculate expressions in the variables, substituting them as is.
Your create table expression results in this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.udr_lt_bc_substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10)...
```

Your second expression results in this:

```
CREATE TABLE concat(substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10),default.udr_lt_bc_)
```

Unfortunately Hive does not support such expressions in DDL.

I recommend to calculate this variable in a shell and pass as a --hivevar to the hive script.

For example in the sell script:

```
table_name=udr_lt_bc_$(date +'%Y_%m_%d' --date "-1 day")
#table_name is udr_lt_bc_2017_10_31 now
#call your script
hive -hivevar table_name="$table_name" -f your_script.hql
```

And then in your_script you can use variable:

```
CREATE TABLE default.${hivevar:table_name}
```

Note that `'-'` is not allowed in table names, that is why i used `'_'` instead.

For better understanding how Hive substitutes variables, try this:

```
hive> set hivevar:tab_dt= substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10);
hive> select ${hivevar:tab_dt};
OK
2017-10-31
Time taken: 1.406 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select '${hivevar:tab_dt}';
OK
substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10)
Time taken: 0.087 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Note that in the first select statement the variable was substituted as is before execution and then calculated in the SQL. Second select statement prevent calculation because the variable is quoted and remains as is: `substr(date_sub(current_date,1),1,10)`.

Comment: Thank you leftjoin for your detailed comment.

Comment: Thank you leftjoin for your detailed comment. Found it very helpful. Infact I did try it in a shell script and it worked well when i executed the sh file from command line. But when i called the same file from a oozie workflow , the hive section in the sh file is not running. my hive query was exactly similar to what you have mentioned. I assigned variables in shell script and then i invoke the hive in the same script as hive -hivevar table_name="$table_name" -f your_script.hql. I then execute this .sh file as a shell action in oozie.  Do you know why this happening ?

Comment: @Sandeep I'd suggest you to post one more question with your script and oozie config

Comment: Thank you I will do that leftjoin

Answer (score 0):

Another way in Hive:

```
select concat("table_",date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),0));
```

Here, we can use above in a variable and use it as per our needs.